# Isekai where a customer service agent takes a call from another world

Tags: story-identification, manga, isekai, webcomics

The site I was using to keep track of what I was reading is currently down and I can't look at anything I was reading

I have looked everywhere and can't seem to find what I was reading here's all that I can remember

The main character is a female and she works at a help line sort of like customer service, someone from another world somehow called her and frequently kept calling her until her ratings slowly went down and she went to visit them she goes into the middle of nowhere and winds up in another world where she finds out the one calling her was the king/emperor/leader

I can't find it for the life of me and I have terrible memory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*[What Kind of Empress Is This](https://www.mangaupdates.com/series.html?id=154658)*

[image: Front cover of *What Kind of Empress is This]

> A customer service worker Jin Ye-Rom has encountered a very troublesome customer, causing her number one employee status to disappear.
> Wanting her status back, she decides to find that customer and personally apologize to him, but, suddenly, she finds herself in a strange place.
> The next thing she knows, she's become the Empress, and that troublesome customer turns out to be none other than the Emperor himself!

Found with a search for `isekai "customer service"`